# how to get next value of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I want when user enter a number, if number was in database, get next value from array
I want get next value from current value in array, but this code go first of array

```
    if ($value['number'] == $number) {

            $result = mysqli_query( $con,"SELECT user_name FROM tbl_users WHERE  user_name ='".$value['name']."'" );
            if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                $iter = new \ArrayIterator($data);
                $iter->next();
                $nextKey = $iter->key();
                $nextValue = $iter->current();
                $user_id = $value['number'];
                $user_name = $value['name'];

            } 
        }
```

Comment: are you running this code inside a loop? to loop over an array?

Comment: yes but its get first  of array value

Comment: please put your full code, or at least provide the outer loop

Comment: @linaa - did my answer helped you? was that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to loop over `mysqli` result ([php documantation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-fetch.php)). you should try this way:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch($result)) {
   $user_id = $row['number'];
   $user_name = $row['name'];
   // do what ever you need with those value
}
```

(also, your `$data` var in the question is not define)

Comment: mysqli better ;)

Comment: I think that $data is a diferent array and the user need iterate in this $data array when sql returns data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the iterator, but you don't need

Change this:

```
$iter = new \ArrayIterator($data);
$iter->next();
$nextKey = $iter->key();
$nextValue = $iter->current();
$user_id = $value['number'];
$user_name = $value['name'];
```

for this:

```
/* This will return an array with "key" and "value" items and advance the array curson one item */
$nextValue = each($data); 
print $nextValue["key"];
print $nextvalue["value"];
```